# Server has lots of disk space in use, running commands to list which folders are taking up lots of space, are not working

Tags: linux, shell, disk-usage, repository

Trying to list folders, specifically git repositories that are taking up most of the disk space within the server.

```
du -x -h /apps/bitbucket-home/shared/data/repositories/ | sort -h | tail -40
```

This doesn't work, the command times out and I get kicked out of the instance. I'm assuming because the instance has a lot of disk space in us, the command above causes performance issues and can't handle the process.

Any idea on how I can partition this request or create a better command to actually process the amount of data in `/apps/bitbucket-home/shared/data/repositories/`?

Comment: I would create a nightly cronjob to generate this data into a text file, so you don't have to run this command during peak hours or when you really need the information.  of course it's possible that a repo spiked dramatically since the last cron job, but I would add some logging to the git server to find those cases.

Comment: `cd /apps/bitbucket-home/shared/data/repositories`, then a series of `du -h -s [Aa]*` commands, with different letters in the brackets (e.g. `[Bb]*`, `[Cc]*`), etc. until you've checked all the repo subdirs.  You can even append the outputs to a file somewhere and run sort -h on the file to get the biggest of all of them.  But if you can find one or two giant ones quickly, you can free up enough space to go back to your `du | sort | tail` command.

Comment: Thank you @SottoVoce, will try your suggestion tomorrow. In my case the repos are identified by numbers, like so: 1, 10002, 10693,  11592  12364,  13709,  14363 , 14998. So instead ill just rely on [10]*, [11]* ..... [20]*, etc... Appending to a file also seems the best approach as well.

Comment: Please explain "command times out": In UNIX no command times out. So the filesystem is remote? If it's git repositories, maybe start with a `git fsck` for each repository, then maybe try a `git gc` for each then.

Comment: @U.Windl, the file system is remote, I get booted out of the server. There are many repositories.

Comment: @SottoVoce is there any way to use [1]* to filter repo's by the amount of digits they contain?

Answer (score 3):

Well, it might be possible to set a `nice` value to adjust the `process priority` and reduce the execution time, but `sudo` is required

```bash
sudo nice -n -10 du -x -h /apps/bitbucket-home/shared/data/repositories/ | sort -h | tail -40
```

Comment: New to linux so apologies for my ignorance, what does -n -10 do here as opposed to -n -5?

Comment: The value range of nice is "20 to +19". The default value is "0". . High `nice` values are low priority and low `nice` values are high priority. When a process is started, it inherits the `nice` value from its parent process. The owner of the process can lower the priority of the process, but cannot increase it. Of course, `root` is free to set the nice value to any value they like.

Comment: Actually for an "I/O heavy" process (like the one described) increasing the priority does very little to nothing to improve the time needed for completion. Only if multiple processes compete for CPU, then the higher priority process will get more CPU than the others. With todays's multi-core/multi-thread CPUs that's hardly ever an issue, however.

Comment: If `load average < 1`, it probably doesn't make sense, try to put it in the background and then redirect the output to a file